# Python - Cannot click hyperlink button with Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am currently working on a program that logs into an account for me and navigates through some webpages

My current issue is that on one of the webpages, I cannot click ANY hyperlink buttons to get to the next page I need to get to. I have tried finding the element waiting to see if it is clickable and using:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, ""))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, ""))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, ""))).click()

and 

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "").click()
(Along with the other methods)
```

However, I have had no success when I invoke a `.click()` after each of those.

After further investigation, I saw that the website uses the same class name for 2 of the elements. I am not sure if this plays any role into not being able to click on the one I need to.

- Element which I am trying to click:

```
<a href="/prod/twbkwbis.P_GenMenu?name=bmenu.P_StuMainMnu" class="submenulinktext2 " onmouseover="window.status='Student'; return true" onmouseout="window.status=''; return true" onfocus="window.status='Student'; return true" onblur="window.status=''; return true">Student</a>

The XPATH: /html/body/div[4]/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a
```

- Element with the same class name as the one above:

```
<a href="/prod/twbksite.P_DispSiteMap?menu_name_in=bmenu.P_MainMnu&amp;depth_in=2&amp;columns_in=3" accesskey="2" class="submenulinktext2">SITE MAP</a>

The XPATH: /html/body/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/p/span/a[2]
```

After seeing them both having the same class name, I tried:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.submenulinktext2"))).click()
```

A thought I was that since the automation is going from one website URL and navigates to another page with a new URL to begin more navigation, that it did not know what URL we were on so I tried:

```
driver.get("NEW URL")
```

And with that in place there has been no success so far, unfortunately. Any guidance on how I can go about this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Considering the HTML of the element:

```
<a href="/prod/twbksite.P_DispSiteMap?menu_name_in=bmenu.P_MainMnu&amp;depth_in=2&amp;columns_in=3" accesskey="2" class="submenulinktext2">SITE MAP</a>
```

The element is a `<a>` tag with innertext as ***Student***.

---

### Solution

However the desired element is a dynamic element. So to click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *LINK_TEXT*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Student"))).click()
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[onmouseover*='Student'][onfocus*='Student']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@onmouseover, 'Student') and contains(@onfocus, 'Student')][text()='Student']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: None of these seem to be working and return a TimeoutException